# Why does Nolan fill his recent hits with permanent noise/music?

Tags: sound-effects, christopher-nolan

I just watched Christopher Nolan's *Dunkirk* (2017) on the big screen, and all I could focus on during the projection was Nolan's permanent use of noise/music that tries to manipulate emotions to the point where it sometimes put the story in the background. I also noticed the same use in *Interstellar* (2014), but not used as intensively as in *Dunkirk*. I'm sure that if I had my blood pressure measured, it'd be in the high for the whole movie, but not because of the story...

Why is he using such a process? Is it because he believes he can't reach us through the story? I would think that the story is good enough without that permanent buzz, so I'm really wondering what he's trying to achieve with that sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is done not because he can't reach us through the story, but because he wants to *amplify* the moment, emotion and feeling you get as a viewer.

As you said story itself is good enough to make you feel those emotions but he wants you to feel them with higher intensity so he's using that music and buzz to make those moments and feelings even stronger.